# Symfony : project creation

Tags: php, symfony

When i try to create a new symfony project using this line of command :
`symfony new project-name` it works fine for me, but unlike this command line :
`symfony new project-name --full` it doesn't install all the packages, and when i try to create the project using the second command line, i get some errors, also i can't create a database with this command line:
`php bin/console doctrine:database:create`

Comment: Are you on windows? Have you installed symfony cli? If you have done that, whats the output of `symfony check:requirements `

Comment: [Avoid using images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) in your questions.  Just copy/paste in a few relevant lines from your errors.  And include your PHP version.

Comment: Yes, i installed symfony cli!

Comment: @Cerad but using images would be more helpful isn't it ?

Comment: @NgatiaFrankline symfony check:requirements :  Your system is ready to run Symfony projects

Comment: The link explains why they are less than helpful.  In fact, you might first try pasting a few lines into your browser's search bar.  Might be surprised to discover what pops up.

Comment: Ohh, i see, got it!

Comment: @Cerad, so do you have any clue for this error ? NoFoundHttpException

Comment: Please also check this guide https://www.osradar.com/how-to-install-symfony-on-windows-10/ and tell us if there is any step you missed especially the `allow firewall` part during the installation.

Comment: Please add all error messages to your question in text form, along with your attempts to resolve them

Answer (score -1):

You can also use composer to create a new project in case the CLI does not work

```
composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton my_project_name
```

Also check if everything is okay with the CLI by running

```
 symfony check:requirements
```

For your database make sure you have configured the database correctly in you `.env` file.
Check this https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#configuring-environment-variables-in-env-files

Comment: Please share more details - why not use Symfony's own CLI for this? And what exactly needs to be configured to resolve the unknown error?